# Major Field Test Sample Questions (need further clarification)

Tags: algorithms

I have several questions that do no make sense for me.

**First Question:**
A stack can be implemented with an array A[0..N-1] and a variable pos. The push and pop operations are defined by the following code.

```
push (x)
  A[pos] <- x
  pos <- pos – 1 
end push

pop ( )
  pos <- pos + 1
  return A[pos] 
end pop
```

Which of the the following will initialize an empty stack with capacity N for this implementation?

a)pos <- -1

b)pos <- 0

c)pos <- 1

d)pos <- N - 1

e)pos <- N

I have zero idea for this question and I dont understand what is being asked

**Second Question:** Consider the following recursive function

```
int Fun ( int n ) 
if ( n == 4 )
  return 2 
 else
  return 2 * Fun ( n + 1 ) 
 end if
end Fun
```

What is the value returned by the function call Fun(2)?

a)2

b)4

c)8

d)16

e)24

The answer is **C** but I got 6 cox this is how I did it, because n is 2 and it not 4 so it return 2 * (2+1) which is equal to 6

**Third Question:** Following is a definition of a widget and a declaration of an array A that contains 10 widgets. The size of a byte, short, int, and long are 1,2,4 and 8 bytes, respectively. Alignment is restricted so that an n-byte field must be located at an address divisible by n. Th fields in a struct are not rearranged padding is used to ensure alignment. All widgets in A must have the same size

```
struct widget 
  short s
  byte b 
  long l 
  int i
end widget 

widget A[10]
```

Assuming that A is located at a memory address divisible by 8, what is the total size of A, in bytes?

a)150

b)160

c)200

d)240

e)320

The answer is **D** but I dont understand why is it D and not C.

Comment: Please consider asking only one question per thread. The 1st
question doesn't make sense to me either, for the 2nd look up "recursion". As for the last one, try drawing the status of the memory for more than one widget.

Answer (score 2):

I will try my best to explain the **first** question.

They are basically asking what value **pos** need to be in order for the stack to be empty. Since we are using an **array** as a stack, we have a choice between **0** or **N-1**. Looking at the code, **Pop increment** **pos** and **push decrement pos**. We want to follow pop because it pops the first element and so on to the last element. If we pop all elements in the array it will equal N-1 values. The answer should be **D**.